# Using Custom Static Table View Cell XIB in Storyboard

Tags: uitableview, xib, uistoryboard, custom-cell

I have a custom static `UITableViewCell` that I want to look exactly the same as a right detail cell (`UILabel` on the left, `UILabel` on the right), except I want the right `UILabel` to be an editable `UITextField`. Since I want to use this cell in multiple view controllers in my storyboard, I decided the best option would be to create a *MyEditableTableViewCell.xib* file, along with corresponding **.h,m* files. I have two public properties in *MyEditableTableViewCell.h*:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *detailTextField;
```

These `IBOutlet`s are connected to the `UILabel` and `UITextField` in the .xib file. In my storyboard, where I have a custom `UITableViewController` subclass, I change the class of the necessary `UITableViewCell` to `MyEditableTableViewCell`. I have a property in my view controller that is:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyEditableTableViewCell *myCell;`

However, when I run the app, the cell appears as simply a blank cell. Running some checks on it, I see that `[myCell isKindOfClass:[MyEditableTableViewCell class]]` returns true. However, the `UITextField` never seems to get instantiated. When I try to alter `myCell.detailTextField.text`, nothing happens, and `myCell.detailTextField` appears to be nil.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How are you creating instances of `MyEditableTableViewCell`?  My guess is you're doing `[[MyEditableTableViewCell alloc] init]` instead of loading them from the nib.

You don't need that property in your view controller.  You need to register your cell nib with the table view using `-[UITableView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:]`.  Do that in your `viewDidLoad`.  Then, when you send `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` to the table view, it will instantiate the nib, creating a `MyEditableTableViewCell`, and return it to you.

#### UPDATE

If you're laying out static cells in a storyboard, using a xib to lay out a cell is somewhat difficult.  The simplest thing to do is simply lay out the cell's subviews in the storyboard.  You can copy and paste the subviews to each cell if you have a few of the same type.

If you really want to use a xib, the easiest way is to structure your cell's view hierarchy like this:

```
MyEditableTableViewCell (in storyboard)
|
+- cell's content view (created automatically by UIKit)
   |
   +- UIView (top-level view of the xib)
      |
      +- UILabel (textLabel)
      |
      +- UITextField (detailTextField)
```

So you set the cell class in the storyboard to `MyEditableTableViewCell`.  Then you create your xib.  You set your xib File's Owner class to `MyEditableTableViewCell`.  The xib **does not** contain a `MyEditableTableViewCell`.  The top-level view of the xib is just a plain `UIView`, containing the subviews (the label and the text field).

In `-[MyEditableTableViewCell initWithCoder:]`, after doing `self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]`, instantiate the xib, passing `self` (the cell) as the xib file's owner.  The cell can have outlets connected to the label and the text field in the xib.

After instantiating the xib, add the top-level view from the xib as a subview of `self.contentView`.  If you're using auto layout, create constraints betwixt the top-level view and the content view.  Otherwise, set the top-level view's `frame` to the content view's `bounds` and set the autoresizing mask to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, these `UITableView`s are static. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is never called, nor are any of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods. The `MyEditableTableViewCell` is placed directly into the `UITableView` in the storyboard. I do need the `IBOutlet` property in my view controller in order to edit its text at runtime.

Comment: Any further advice on this, Rob?

Comment: If you are using static table view cells in a storyboard, those cells must be laid out in the storyboard.  You can't put them in a separate xib.

Comment: So there's no way to reuse a static configuration? I just need to lay it out every time I want to use it? If that's the case, update your answer, and I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I apologize for the really late comment - but is there any explaination to why it isn't possible to lay out a cell in a seperate xib, then load that uitableview's xib into a static table view? I understand you cannot do this, but I'd really like to learn why.

Answer (score 0):

Although a static table view will not fetch your cell from the nib, it will still call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  There you can dequeue and return your fully unarchived custom cell. Properties on the custom cell that were set in IB, can be fetched by calling super on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // get an empty cell with properties retained from IB
    UITableViewCell *sup = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([sup isKindOfClass:[MyCustomCell class]]) {
          // fetch a fully unarchived cell
          MyCustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"foo" forIndexPath:indexPath];

          // copy properties over...
          [cell copyPropertiesFromCell:(MyCustomCell *)sup];

          return cell;
    }
    return sup;
}
```

Depending on the situation, this might actually be easier than to mess with IB objects.